# Some time Invalid json string is coming

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, redux, axios

I am using React native 0.55.0 . For api i am using Axios,  Some time i am getting invalid json

*I am getting some time json invalid string with adding invalid string eg "type_name" to "ty"type_name". Api on server side is working correctly . Some time it's working correctly with json object, Not getting whats this issue is*

Action file

```
export function getNotifications(params):Action {
  return (dispatch) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: SET_NOTIFICATIONS_LIST_REQUEST
                })
        return getNotificationsApi(params).then(resp => {
                            var data = resp.data
                             alert(typeof data) //it's return string
                             console.log(data)
                             dispatch(getNotificationsSuccess(data))
                return resp.data
            }).catch(err =>     {
                        })
    }
}
```

Data which i got

```
{"data":[{"id":583,"type":"itemcomment","type_id":10036,"datetime":"2018-05-15T06:48:39","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"test new","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}},{"id":581,"type":"itemcomment","type_id":10036,"datetime":"2018-05-15T06:48:05","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"test new","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}},{"id":578,"type":"itemcomment","type_id":10036,"datetime":"2018-05-15T06:42:50","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"test new","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}},{"id":449,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-09T10:48:15","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":430,"type":"edititem","type_id":10034,"datetime":"2018-05-08T07:59:29","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item3","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524568505IMG_0344.PNG"},{"image":"1525761327virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"}]},{"id":427,"type":"edititem","type_id":10034,"datetime":"2018-05-08T06:35:26","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item3","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524568505IMG_0344.PNG"},{"image":"1525761327virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"}]},{"id":424,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-08T05:44:08","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":421,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-08T05:38:41","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":418,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-08T05:38:29","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":355,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-03T05:44:22","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":353,"type":"edititem","type_id":10025,"datetime":"2018-05-02T12:03:54","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item1","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524201903virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"},{"image":"1524201903IMG_0190.PNG"}]},{"id":351,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-05-02T05:48:26","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":283,"type":"addoutfits","type_id":8,"datetime":"2018-04-24T12:26:24","status":1,"user_id":6,"type_name":"Testttttt","user":{"username":"user2","id":"6","first_name":"sonam","last_name":"dogra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139232IMG_0186.PNG"},"oufitimg":"1524572784newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":250,"type":"additem","type_id":10034,"datetime":"2018-04-24T11:15:05","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item3","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524568505IMG_0344.PNG"},{"image":"1525761327virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"}]},{"id":235,"type":"editoutfits","type_id":3,"datetime":"2018-04-24T10:18:03","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Outfit1","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525261115newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":232,"type":"addoutfits","type_id":5,"datetime":"2018-04-24T10:17:49","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Test","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525758248newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":225,"type":"addoutfits","type_id":3,"datetime":"2018-04-24T10:10:26","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Outfit1","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"oufitimg":"1525261115newlookImage.jpg"},{"id":207,"type":"likeitem","type_id":10026,"datetime":"2018-04-23T12:46:53","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item2","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}},{"id":206,"type":"itemcomment","type_id":10032,"datetime":"2018-04-23T12:35:29","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}},{"id":190,"type":"additem","type_id":10026,"datetime":"2018-04-20T05:31:30","status":1,"user_id":8,"ty"type_name":"Item2","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524202290IMG_0125.PNG"},{"image":"1524202290virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"},{"image":"1524202290virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"}]},{"id":187,"type":"additem","type_id":10025,"datetime":"2018-04-20T05:25:03","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"Item1","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"},"itemimg":[{"image":"1524201903virtual_closet_mobile.jpg"},{"image":"1524201903IMG_0190.PNG"}]},{"id":60,"type":"acceptrequest","type_id":8,"datetime":"2018-04-19T17:23:46","status":1,"user_id":8,"type_name":"","user":{"username":"user4","id":"8","first_name":"ruhi","last_name":"vohra"},"user_meta":{"value":"1524139730IMG_0189.JPG"}}],"result":"success","image_path":"img\\/users"}
```

*Please help if anyone can*
*Is this memory issue*

Comment: Can you please give more details of your getNotificationsApi() to make sure you are not overriding the default transformResponse with your own. The default transformResponse will parse JSON.

Comment: `export const getNotificationsApi = (params) => {
  return client.post('getAllnotification', params)
} `

*const client = axios.create({
 baseURL: BASE_URL + API_PREFIX,
 headers: {"Accept-Encoding": 'gzip,deflate'},
 transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat((data) => {
   return data;
  })
})*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error may be caused by your function overriding the default transformResponse which can parse json for you.

Please see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/430#issuecomment-243481806 post for accepted answer by Matt Zabriskie.

Also, please don't use 'var' with ES6 syntax but this is minor.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mattyao . I have struggled with this issue in last 3 days